Conform to iOS 17.0's Use Map initializers that take a MapContentBuilder
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

extension MKCoordinateRegion: Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: MKCoordinateRegion, rhs: MKCoordinateRegion) -> Bool {
        lhs.center.latitude == rhs.center.latitude &&
            lhs.center.longitude == rhs.center.longitude &&
            lhs.span.latitudeDelta == rhs.span.latitudeDelta &&
            lhs.span.longitudeDelta == rhs.span.longitudeDelta
    }
}

struct TestMap: View {
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.7749, longitude: -122.4194),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
    )

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
                .onChange(of: region) { newRegion in
                    printRegionDetails(newRegion)
                }
        }
    }

    private func printRegionDetails(_ region: MKCoordinateRegion) {
        let center = region.center
        // Approximate radius in meters, based on the latitude delta
        let radius = (region.span.latitudeDelta * 111_000) / 2

        print("Center: \(center.latitude), \(center.longitude)")
        print("Current radius (approx): \(radius) meters")
        print("\n")
    }
}

// MARK: - PREVIEW

struct TestMap_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestMap()
    }
}

I'm getting the warnings

'init(coordinateRegion:interactionModes:showsUserLocation:userTrackingMode:)' was deprecated in iOS 17.0: Use Map initializers that take a MapContentBuilder instead.
'onChange(of:perform:)' was deprecated in iOS 17.0: Use onChange with a two or zero parameter action closure instead.

I tried many variations but all gave me errors. I can't seem to understand apple's documentations on this.

For onChange, use .onChange(of: region) { _, newRegion in. For the Map issue, see https://useyourloaf.com/blog/mapkit-for-swiftui/

"Use Map initializers that take a MapContentBuilder instead" Like this, for example: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map/4231665-init If even that's too obscure, how about just watching the introductory video? https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10043/

The new APIs do not include an overload of Map.init() that takes a Binding<MKCoordinateRegion>. Instead, you should use onMapCameraChange to detect changes in the map region:
@State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
    center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.7749, longitude: -122.4194),
    span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
)

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // the region can be passed as the initial position of the map camera instead
        Map(initialPosition: .region(region))
            .onMapCameraChange(frequency: .continuous) {
                printRegionDetails($0.region)
            }
    }
}

You can pass a frequency parameter, either .continuous or .onEnd, to indicate whether you want to detect a change every frame, or only when the map camera stops moving.
